# how to cancel some click events in document in JQuery (not all of them)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Click on the document, the `.area` div disappears.

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
    $('.area').hide();
});

$(document).off('click', '.red', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

In this case, how can I apply stopPropagation to `.red`. I'd like to keep this js format, as I will need to add more class names.

**Online Sample** http://jsfiddle.net/ku9cj/1/

Thanks

Comment: BTW `'$('.red')'` is an error. Either escape or mix quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`off()` is used to remove the event handler; you need to use `.on()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.red', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/242r2/)

Answer (score 1):

You should not attach handlers to the document, as they bubble up very slowly. If you must do so, try the following:

```
$('body').on('click', function() {
    $('.area').hide();
});

$('.red').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Or, if you insist on using a delegate and do not have a closer parent element:

```
$('body').on('click', '.red', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed information. it helps understand more. I was thinking how to use "off" to remove click area (div).